# C# order listview by column?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im building a datatable with 2 columns with listview and i need to order the datatable by the second column.

It look something like this:

Name - Points 
------------------ 
John      -  10 
Peter      -  14 
Marcus  -  9 

So how do I order it by points?


**SOLVED!!**

```
        private class PointsComparer : IComparer
        {
            private const int pointsColumnIndex = 1;

            public int Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                ListViewItem listX = (ListViewItem)x;
                ListViewItem listY = (ListViewItem)y;

                // Convert column text to numbers before comparing.
                // If the conversion fails, just use the value 0.
                decimal listXVal, listYVal;
                try
                {
                    listXVal = Decimal.Parse(listX.SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
                }
                catch
                {
                    listXVal = 0;
                }

                try
                {
                    listYVal = Decimal.Parse(listY.SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
                }
                catch
                {
                    listYVal = 0;
                }

                return (-Decimal.Compare(listXVal, listYVal));
            }
        }
```

This worked as a charm for me.

Comment: If you dont need to reorder later you can order in select query.

Comment: Is it winforms, or what?

Comment: Strange, its very similar to my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ListViewItemSorter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter.aspx) property to set custom `IComparer` for your items. Then simply call `Sort()` method:

```
// adding data
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "John", "10" }));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Peter", "14" }));
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "Markus", "9" }));
// setting comparer and sorting
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new PointsComparer();
listView1.Sort();
```

Here is sample of comparer which you can use to compare points:

```
private class PointsComparer : IComparer
{
    private const int pointsColumnIndex = 1;

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int pointsX = Int32.Parse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
        int pointsY = Int32.Parse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
        return pointsX.CompareTo(pointsY);
    }
}
```

Or, as I posted previously, you can use comparer by column text from msdn sample.

UPDATE: You can pass desired sort order to instance of your comparer:

```
private class PointsComparer : IComparer
{
    private const int pointsColumnIndex = 1;
    private SortOrder _sortOrder;            

    public PointsComparer(SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        _sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int pointsX = Int32.Parse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
        int pointsY = Int32.Parse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[pointsColumnIndex].Text);
        int comparisonResult = pointsX.CompareTo(pointsY);

        switch (_sortOrder)
        {
            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                return comparisonResult;
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                return (-1) * comparisonResult;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new PointsComparer(SortOrder.Descending);
```

Comment: "property to set custom IComparer for your items."

What?

Comment: If you are using winforms, then ListView control has property `ListViewItemSorter`. Create your own sorter, which compares items and set it as listview sorter.

Comment: If you want descending sorting, use `return pointsY.CompareTo(pointsX);` instead, or multiply comparison result by `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
datatableinstance.DefaultView.Sort = "Points ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDt.DefaultView.Sort = "Points";
DataView dv = yourDt.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;  
   //apply the sort on CustomerSurname column  
   dv.Sort = "CustomerSurname";  
   //save our newly ordered results back into our datatable  
   dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

> // Sorting data based on ID
>
> Let's suppose dt is your datatable object to be sorted. You can do as
>   mentioned below:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Points ASC";
```

> now dt is your sorted datatable

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out with the same issue. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

I found that I had to tweak some of the math as when sorting by numbers it sometimes would put 1,10,11,12,2,20,21,etc

Answer (score 0):

here are some samples

Paste the following code into the ColumnClick event for the ListView control:

```
 private void listView1_OnColumnClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewSorter Sorter = new ListViewSorter();
        listView1.ListViewItemSorter = Sorter;
        if (!(listView1.ListViewItemSorter is ListViewSorter))
            return;
        Sorter = (ListViewSorter) listView1.ListViewItemSorter;

        if (Sorter.LastSort == e.Column)
        {
            if (listView1.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
            else
                listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else{
            listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
        }
        Sorter.ByColumn = e.Column;

        listView1.Sort ();
    }
```

---

```
   public class ListViewSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
    {
        public int Compare (object o1, object o2)
        {
            if (!(o1 is ListViewItem))
                return (0);
            if (!(o2 is ListViewItem))
                return (0);

            ListViewItem lvi1 = (ListViewItem) o2;
            string str1 = lvi1.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;
            ListViewItem lvi2 = (ListViewItem) o1;
            string str2 = lvi2.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

            int result;
            if (lvi1.ListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                result = String.Compare (str1, str2);
            else
                result = String.Compare (str2, str1);

            LastSort = ByColumn;

            return (result);
        }


        public int ByColumn
        {
            get {return Column;}
            set {Column = value;}
        }
        int Column = 0;

        public int LastSort
        {
            get {return LastColumn;}
            set {LastColumn = value;}
        }
        int LastColumn = 0;
    }
```

sort sample
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

multi sort

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/sort-a-multicolumn-listview-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Thats really not what im looking for.

Comment: then what are u looking for. Eighter want to sort on datatable or on listview where exectly you are looking to sort the data. if on DT then you can use the dataview to sort data as     dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Points ASC";

Comment: I want to be able to click a button to sort the second column so ican sort it after ive added items dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

As Reniuz said, For better performance order it within the SQL query and for Xtra-gain implement it in a dictionary or an arrayList or a Generic List ( List ) and also you can use Datagridview to show on GUI .. SQL Query Syntax :

```
Select [Column1], [Column2] from [YourTable] order by [ColumnWhichYouWantToOrder1], [ColumnWhichYouWantToOrder2] [ {ASC} or {DESC} ]
```

Rules for Syntax :

- DESC ordering sorts from last no to first or Z to A
- ASC ordering sorts from first to last or A to Z
- ASC is the default. So if you order by ASC you can use as ..order by [Column] ... no need to write ASC
- when you sort with more than 1 column, SQL starts to order from left column to right.